# Determining the color space for a range of bytes?

Tags: colors, hex

I'm working on [this open-source ruby library](https://github.com/hired/limitless-led) for changing the color of [these certain networked lights](http://www.limitlessled.com/). The issue I'm having is determining the color space of the single byte that is sent to change the color. Additionally [their docs are a bit confusing](http://www.limitlessled.com/dev/) and unclear too.

Here is what I know, [when I send the byte: 0x00](https://github.com/hired/limitless-led/blob/master/lib/limitless_led.rb#L59), It's violet (like at the 12 o'clock position on the image on their homepage), then as you move clockwise around the dial it ends up at 0xff back at the top, so there are 256 possible colors.

My question is how do I convert something like RGB to this single byte ranging from 0x00 - 0xff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can find black and white and then calibrate from there. When you have enough points, you can devise a functional relationship, assuming it's linear and continuous.

Comment: I believe the color space is related to HSB because I think I only have access to the hue in this instance. Brightness seems to be the other parameter available to me, but is controlled independently from the hue in this case.